# How to send values in diff name in each iteration of for loop in jsp page

Tags: jsp, spring-batch

I'm doing a small project using jsp.

```
<form action="a.jsp">
    <table>
    <%
    for(i=1;i<=nor;i++){
%>
<tr  bgcolor="#fdeaeb" height="25">
<td width="100"><input type="text" class="s_txt" value="<%=i%>" readonly /></td>
<td width="100">
      <select name="ad" class="date">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    </td>
<td width="100">
     <select name="ch" class="date">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
    </td>
<td width="100">
     <select name="ca" class="date">
  <option value="8">>7</option>
  <option value="7"><=7</option>
 </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<%
}
}catch(Exception e){
       out.print(e);
    }
%>
<tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" class="newsletter_submit" value="Next" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here the table is created dynamically depending on "nor" value.My problem is how can I receive all the table values through request.getParameter() in a.jsp bcoz all the elements are passed in a same name.How can I send the values in a diff name in each iteration.?
plz help

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
for(i=1;i<=nor;i++){
%>
<tr  bgcolor="#fdeaeb" height="25">
<td width="100"><input type="text" class="s_txt" value="<%=i%>" readonly /></td>
<td width="100">
      <select name="ad<%=i%>" class="date">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
```

Repeat for the other fields. (the relevent part is <%=i%> which prints the current iteration number) So that way all the fields get different names, thus are addressable.